# duplicity resumption of partial backup compares all files?

Tags: duplicity, duplicity-backup

When `duplicity` resumes a partial backup, it goes through all files from the beginning. Maybe it compares if the already backed up files have changed ever since. This is slow as I have backed up terabytes of data and I know that they have not changed.

```
Found 531 volumes in manifest
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup left a partial set, restarting.
Last full backup date: Fri Oct  6 14:41:16 2023

Processing local manifest b'duplicity-full.20231006T184116Z.manifest.part' (157879)
Found 531 volumes in manifest
RESTART: Volumes 530 to 531 failed to upload before termination.
         Restarting backup at volume 530.
Skipping encryption validation due to glacier/deep storage
Restarting after volume 529, file hello/world.nii.gz, block 14
```

Is there a way to tell `duplicity` to start looking at files only after volume `529`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved this by adding the already backed up directories in `profile/exclude` file. Still, if you know a better way to solve this, please answer.